# Loading children data from an API when expanding on ExpansionTile in Flutter

Tags: flutter, future, expansion

The idea is, I have main categories, to which have their own id, when the user expands the tile (should it be fetchFromApi), it will grab the data from the api (in this case, a mock asset json file) and display it as tiles.

I am struggling to get the right mechanism in order to load it. I presume set the state? I have tried with futurebuilder as I did want a loading icon to appear as it is loading but I can't seem to get the idea correctly. Suggestions on how to implement this would be appreciated.

This is my class right now.

```
class DrawerNavigationPart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Category> mainCategories = Categories.categoryData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: mainCategories.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final Category category = mainCategories[index];
        if (category.fetchFromApi) {
          List<Category> api = [];
          return ExpansionTile(
            key: PageStorageKey<Category>(category),
            leading: Icon(category.icon),
            title: Text(
              category.title,
              softWrap: false,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            onExpansionChanged: (bool open) async {
              if (open) {
                String response = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString(
                        'assets/822828-2228222-2222#category-api-mock.json');
                api = categoryResponseFromJson(response).data;
                print(api);
              }
            },
            children: [
//              FutureBuilder(
//                  future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
//                      'assets/822828-2228222-2222#category-api-mock.json'),
//                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
//                    final CategoryResponse categoryResponse =
//                        categoryResponseFromJson(snapshot.data);
////                    return ListView.builder(
////                        itemCount: 3,
////                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
////                          return Text(index.toString());
////                        });
//                    return ListTile(
//                        title: Text(categoryResponse.data[index].title));
//                  })
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(category.icon),
            title: Text(
              category.title,
              softWrap: false,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              print(category.title + ' clicked');
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Category root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty)
      return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(root.icon),
        title: Text(
          root.title,
          softWrap: false,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          print("${root.title} listTile clicked");
        },
      );
    return ExpansionTile(
      key: PageStorageKey<Category>(root),
      leading: Icon(root.icon),
      title: Text(
        root.title,
        softWrap: false,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
      onExpansionChanged: (bool open) {
        print("${root.title} expansionTile clicked $open");
      },
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

StatelessWidget is not changed view

so use StatefulWidget and State Class

for example

```
class  DrawerNavigationPart extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _DrawerNavigationPart();
} 

class _DrawerNavigationPart extends State<DrawerNavigationPart> {

    
  final List<Category> mainCategories = Categories.categoryData;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: mainCategories.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final Category category = mainCategories[index];
        if (category.fetchFromApi) {
          List<Category> api = [];
          return ExpansionTile(
            key: PageStorageKey<Category>(category),
            leading: Icon(category.icon),
            title: Text(
              category.title,
              softWrap: false,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            onExpansionChanged: (bool open) async {
              if (open) {
                String response = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString(
                    'assets/822828-2228222-2222#category-api-mock.json');
                api = categoryResponseFromJson(response).data;
                print(api);
              }
            },
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: getJsonData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final CategoryResponse categoryResponse =
                        categoryResponseFromJson(snapshot.data);
//                    return ListView.builder(
//                        itemCount: 3,
//                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
//                          return Text(index.toString());
//                        });
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text(categoryResponse.data[index].title));
                  })
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(category.icon),
            title: Text(
              category.title,
              softWrap: false,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              print(category.title + ' clicked');
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Category root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty)
      return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(root.icon),
        title: Text(
          root.title,
          softWrap: false,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          print("${root.title} listTile clicked");
        },
      );
    return ExpansionTile(
      key: PageStorageKey<Category>(root),
      leading: Icon(root.icon),
      title: Text(
        root.title,
        softWrap: false,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
      onExpansionChanged: (bool open) {
        print("${root.title} expansionTile clicked $open");
      },
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  Future<String> getJsonData() async {
    var str = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
        'assets/822828-2228222-2222#category-api-mock.json');
    return str;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rollcake, there still seems to be some fundamental problems with it for me. I did (snapshot.hasData) logic inside the futurebuilder but getting errors like: Expected a value of type 'double', but got one of type 'bool'. Also, wouldn't this futurebuilder be called on build?

Comment: yes but futurebuilder is asyncTask at Android , dafa logic process in future parameter

Comment: I solved my issue, I think. Will post my solution. Nontheless, your code gave me some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I made myself a stateful widget for my tile, so I could put different parameters inside. Probably, isn't the best but it seems to work and may help someone else.

Notes of worth:

- Set api variable when it has been opened. If api is empty, it will show loading.

Things to improve:

- Error handling
- If state is already open, it won't flag it to go off again

One of my main issues afterwards was it was saying notEmpty was not a valid option. I had to remember to initialise the empty array as [] rather than null in my response model.

```
     class DrawerNavigationPart extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<Category> mainCategories = Categories.categoryData;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mainCategories.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final Category category = mainCategories[index];
            if (category.fetchFromApi) {
              return MyExpansionTile(
                category: category,
              );
            } else {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(category.icon),
                title: Text(
                  category.title,
                  softWrap: false,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  print(category.title + ' clicked');
                },
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
      final Category category;
    
      const MyExpansionTile({Key key, this.category}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _MyExpansionTileState createState() => _MyExpansionTileState();
    }
    
    class _MyExpansionTileState extends State<MyExpansionTile> {
      List<Category> api;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ExpansionTile(
          key: PageStorageKey<Category>(widget.category),
          leading: Icon(widget.category.icon),
          title: Text(
            widget.category.title,
            softWrap: false,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          onExpansionChanged: (bool open) async {
            if (open) {
              getJsonData(widget.category.id).then((value) => setState(() {
                    api = categoryResponseFromJson(value).data;
                  }));
            }
          },
          children: [
            if (api != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < api.length; i++) _buildTiles(api[i])
            else
              CircularProgressIndicator()
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Widget _buildTiles(Category root) {
        if (root.children.isEmpty)
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(root.icon),
            title: Text(
              root.title,
              softWrap: false,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              print("${root.title} listTile clicked");
            },
          );
        return ExpansionTile(
          key: PageStorageKey<Category>(root),
          leading: Icon(root.icon),
          title: Text(
            root.title,
            softWrap: false,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          onExpansionChanged: (bool open) {
            print("${root.title} expansionTile clicked $open");
          },
          children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
        );
      }
    
      Future<String> getJsonData(String id) async {
        var str = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
            .loadString('assets/822828-2228222-2222#category-api-mock.json');
        return str;
      }
    }
```